# How to filter by part of value using OData?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, odata

I have a table where lies some data and I change shown data according to some conditions (using OData).
For example:

```
"(LastDate eq null or LastDate ge datetime'" + date + "')"
```

or

```
"Status eq 0"
```

Now I need to filer what is shown in my table by some value from textbox and there are problem. I have used second thing:

```
"(Order eq '" + search + "' or SellerName eq '" + search + "' or ItemType eq '" + search + "' or ItemDescription eq '" + search + "')"
```

Works fine EXCEPT that this is eq. I need to find item not only by full match. I saw that there could be used so called [contains](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/), but I didn't get how it supposed to look if I have many `or`. And... I simply reveived `An unknown function with name 'contains' was found` error.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

the .net implementation of OData has support for "substringof" that works the same as you would expect a contains to work.
eg:

```
filter=substringof(SellerName, ‘urn’)
```

Returns records with SellerNames containing the string “urn”.

You can or them togeather like what you have already with eq.

```
filter=substringof(SellerName, ‘urn’) or substringof(Order, ‘urn’)
```

See here for more details:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169248%28v=nav.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below
var columnVal = value.toLowerCase();

?$filter= (indexof(tolower(COLUMN_ID), columnVal)) gt -1

This is working for me.